# Python XML parse issues

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Currently trying to parse some XML using python, so far I've managed to get the name of the tag however  I can't figure out how to get the data from inside this.

```
 <Fragment name="Located At">Sector 121212</Fragment>
```

The above is an example of the XML file, I can get the "Located At" part out but not the "Sector 165658" I am currently using the following:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('file.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Fragment')
for items in itemlist:
print (items.attributes['name'].value)
```

I can't for the life of me remember that the "name" for the section is I feel like this is going to be a simple answer and I'm going to look like an idiot but we shall see.

Comment: `itemlist[0].childNodes[0].wholeText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`minidom` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html), it looks like `.childNodes` might be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that feel so silly!

print (s.attributes['name'].value, s.childNodes) does the job :)

Comment: You're welcome! We all have days where the simplest stuff is the hardest ;)